# Java named entity recognition library for Persons Name "Parts"

Tags: java, named-entity-recognition

My current project needs to improve the data quality of our customers details.

One issue we have is that customers names have seperate data capture input fields for First, Middle names and surnames, however in many cases each part of the name was entered incorrectly.

We need to clean up the data we hold.

This data quality issue impacts when we contact our customers in correspondance, because we do not know their first name, middle names and surnames we offend some customers by using an inappropriate salutation

We need a named entity recognition library that can not only detect PERSONS names, but also detct First, Middle and Surnames.

What makes this data quality task harder is that we have almost 100 million customers, our customer base is world wide so we need to be able to identify first , middle and surnames, e.g. Given name, patronymic, and different ordr of parts. what will help is that we also know the customers nationallity.

Does a named entity recognition exist specific for Person Name PARTS?

I realise that a "Perfect" solution is impossible, however I am sure I can improve the data quality we currently have.

I just mentioned First, Middle and surnames as thats name structure I am most familiar with, however i do understand the following are examples of what I am facing

```
In many parts of the world, parts of names are derived from titles, locations, genealogical information, caste, religious references, and so on. Here are a few examples:

    the Indian name Kogaddu Birappa Timappa Nair follows the order villageName-fathersName-givenName-lastName.
    the Rajasthani name Aditya Pratap Singh Chauhan is composed of givenName-fathersName-surname-casteName.

    in another part of India the name Madurai Mani Iyer represents townName-givenName-casteName.

    the Arabic Abu Karim Muhammad al-Jamil ibn Nidal ibn Abdulaziz al-Filistini translates as "Father of Karim, Muhammad (given name), The beautiful, Son of Nidal, Son of Abdulaziz, the Palestinian". Karim is Muhammad's first-born son.
```

Comment: In a worldwide database, you need to deal with people whose names do not follow the First, Middle, Surname pattern at all.

Comment: Also there are not uncommon cases when in any language or nationality  surname may be a word matching any common first name in that language. eg. John Jack. And most probably the order will be no guaranteed. 
To have anything better than nothing I would go for implementing some best guess heuristics based on first names' database for given language/nationality including popularity which is usually available as some public reports.

Comment: To give a couple of extremes, consider [Sugiarto, who uses only one name,](http://wclv.ideastream.org/news/npr/396815303) and [His Royal Highness Prince William Arthur Philip Louis Duke of Cambridge](http://time.com/3846932/royal-baby-birth-certificate/).

Comment: Consider this W3C article: [Personal names around the world](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names)

Comment: for special cases of royality and VIP's in general we have a specific data quality department that corrects these cases as a matter of urgency. We cannot use this approach for all 100 million customers though.

Comment: @McDowell i have seen that article, it describes succinctly all my pain points.

Comment: my response to the close votes is still valid: What value is there in closing this question? My question is not spam, its a "Real" question related to a "Real" issue, all i am after is expert help in resolving this issue. By closing my question my issue doesn't disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple, universal solution that companies seem surprisingly unwilling to apply:

Include a salutation if, and only if, the communication really is from a human being who is preparing that communication specifically for the recipient. In that case, part of paying attention to the recipient is writing a correct salutation taking into account the recipient's culture.

If you are computer-generating a communication using names from a database, be honest about what you are doing. Simply show the name as it was supplied to you on whatever form it came from. Do not attempt to use it to construct a formal salutation. Do not change it in any way. Communications that are obviously computer-generated but that try to pretend individual attention just look silly, even if they are not sufficiently incorrect to cause actual annoyance.

Comment: My company is a MASSIVE financial organisation, our snail mail monthly print process regularly post 30 million letters, the salutation has to be Present & Correct; but nice idea

Comment: I don't get the logic for going from the fact of extreme mass production to a need for a salutation. If anything, the greater the mass production the more laughable any attempt at personalization looks.

Comment: its not mass production of the same letter, my organisation has a legal obligation to inform its customers of T&C's changes to their individual financial agreements. products that include pensions, mortgages, insurance etc. These letters have to have a certain "Tone Of Voice", something formal and business like.

Comment: @Hector As an investor I am often the recipient of T&C and similar letters from the large bank that manages most of my accounts and a stockbroker that manages a couple more. I assure you I know perfectly well that those businesses are sending out tens of millions of letters, and not at all impressed by "Tone of Voice".